# Dynamic page height to show 10 records per page with StretchWithOverflow property set to true

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 10 records per page (9 columns) in jasper using page break property. I have set StretchWithOverflow property to true for my detail band. So, when there is more data, my table gets enlarge vertically.
My problem is, if the data is more, it is not showing 10 records per page because in jasper we give static height of the page.

If i set more height of the page, then in that case if data is less, there is lots of invalid space on the report. Please help if someone faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.
I used frame (from Pallete ctrl+shift+8) within detail band and put all my cell data into frame. So, when page height is more, the blank space display instead of my last row height go increases. 
Now, my cell could not stretched due to extra height of the page.